# How to render on the GPU instead of CPU? -Java-

Tags: java, rendering, gpu, cpu

In a game I am writing in Java, I am constantly (100 times a second) calling a function called render(Graphics g)

Clearly, this takes a parameter, of Graphics g, and I was wondering how to push all rendering (the render() function) to the GPU in my system, and the updating of the game would be left to my CPU.

Is this very difficult? I would assume it could be.

Comment: You can make all Java2D operations use OpenGL by [setting the sun.java2d.opengl system property](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/2d/new_features.html#ogl).

Answer (score 1):

Use existing [JOCL](http://www.jocl.org/) or [JCUDA](http://www.jcuda.org/)  libraries for this task.